# Add column that does not refresh in powerquery / excel

Tags: excel, powerquery

I try to combine a power query generated view with a column for user input during a review session.
I would like to prevent this column from changing upon data refresh.

```
  A   |  B
--------------
Stats | Review
Long  | good
Short | bad
```

A can update. B is unknown at query time and therefore created with empty values. It is populated by the user. I want to update A, but don't remove the values in B.

I tried to add column B in excel instead of power query, after generating the query to an Excel table. It kind of works as the values stay in the column. However, the order is messed up when I refresh.

Ultimately I think this might be possible with power query when generating the table.

Can this command be modified to get the desired behavior on the column?

```
Table.AddColumn(#"A", "B", each null)
```

*Sorry for the bad example, its kind of hard to show proper excel/powerquery 'code'.*

Comment: If you are looking to be able to maintain static values against a dynamic table, see https://exceleratorbi.com.au/self-referencing-tables-power-query/